# Is it possible to stream a windows (7 / vista / xp) webcams via Gstreamer

Tags: python, windows, streaming, gstreamer

I very new to the world of gstreamer. I was wondering, if it's possible to stream windows webcam via gstreamer? The only package i have seen so far is for linux. v4l2 (video for linux).
Is there also a package for windows webcams? what is the correct python syntax?

DJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows streaming, I would suggest VLC.

Answer (score 5):

Install on windows from http://code.google.com/p/ossbuild/

then use below command

```
gst-launch ksvideosrc device-index=0 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```